# Please help me set new order status for bank transfer payment to pending

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, payment-banktransfer

I went to `Admin Panel > Sales > Payment Methods > Bank Transfer Payment > New Order Status`. I updated it to "pending" however when I place a new order the status still went to "processing".

I tried this. I went to `code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php`:

```
protected function _authorize($isOnline, $amount)
{
    // update totals
    $amount = $this->_formatAmount($amount, true);
    $this->setBaseAmountAuthorized($amount);

    // do authorization
    $order  = $this->getOrder();
    $state  = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
    $status = true;
```

I changed the `STATE_PROCESSING` to `STATE_NEW` to set it on "pending" but when I place a new order the status still went to "processing".

[My Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8787/problem-in-magento-default-order-status-changes/19077#19077)

How can I change the new order status to pending for bank transfer?

My Magento version is 1.9.0.1

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom Magento module can do this task. Let’s name it **Atwix_Orderhook**.

**Step 1 :** First,Create a module initializer in /app/etc/modules/Atwix_Orderhook.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_Orderhook>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Atwix_Orderhook>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step 2:** Create a module configuration file `config.xml` in `/app/code/community/NAMESPACE/MODULENAME/etc/` (replace NAMESPACE and MODULENAME with your own values). In our case the path will be `/app/code/community/Atwix/Orderhook/etc/`. `config.xml` content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_Orderhook>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Atwix_Orderhook>
    </modules>
 
    <global>
 
        <models>            
            <orderhook>
                <class>Atwix_Orderhook_Model</class>
            </orderhook>
        </models>
 
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <auto_invoice_order>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Atwix_Orderhook_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
                    </auto_invoice_order>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
 
    </global>
</config>
```

Step 3 Create observer file `app/code/community/Atwix/Orderhook/Model/Observer.php` with the following content:

```
<?php
 
class Atwix_Orderhook_Model_Observer 
{
    public function implementOrderStatus($event)
    {
        $order = $event->getOrder();
 
        if ($this->_getPaymentMethod($order) == 'banktransfer') {
            if ($order->canInvoice())
                $this->_processOrderStatus($order);
        }
        return $this;
    }
 
    private function _getPaymentMethod($order)
    {
        return $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
    }
 
    private function _processOrderStatus($order)
    {
        $invoice = $order->prepareInvoice();
 
        $invoice->register();
      /*  Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
           ->addObject($invoice)
           ->addObject($invoice->getOrder())
           ->save();*/
 
        $invoice->sendEmail(true, '');
        $this->_changeOrderStatus($order);
        return true;
    }
 
    private function _changeOrderStatus($order)
    {
        $statusMessage = '';
        $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);        
    $order->save();
    }
}
```

Save this module and clear your cache.
[For more see here.](https://www.atwix.com/magento/auto-invoice-and-custom-order-status-upon-checkout/)

Comment: The order status went to "pending" however it still went to "processing". I'll post a screenshot in my question.

Comment: Make sure this module is working  add Mage::log('working',null,'pay.log'); in implementOrderStatus function and see log folder

Comment: Yes, it worked and it created the pay.log file. The screenshot I posted has 2 "pending" statuses. The second "pending" status was because of the code you suggested. I think the observer should be called after "processing" status? I also have a feeling that it goes to "processing" because it auto generates an invoice however I can't find a way to try that yet (can't find anything in google lol). I had typo with this comment I just updated it.

Comment: comment 
        Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
           ->addObject($invoice)
           ->addObject($invoice->getOrder())
           ->save(); this line

Comment: please see the updated the answer

Comment: I'm sorry but it didn't work. Actually, I already tried removing _processOrderStatus function and edited the code to suit my need but still failed lol. Do you know how to move the observer after the invoice is generated in magento? or any suggestions just for me not be stuck.

Comment: Please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046530/magento-order-status-change-events or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357622/trigger-observer-on-magento-order-status-change-events