# Initial order status to Pending?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

As I understand in Magento it sets the status of a new order to processing and then goes away and sorts out  the payment etc.

The problem is that if the payment gateway for worldpay fails/crashes etc it then means I have an order that is set to processing even though no payment has been made.

Unfortunately the software we have interprets processing as ordered and to send it.  Therefore to fix I need to somehow set the initial order status to Pending, which I believe will fix it.  So my question is how do I set the initial status of all orders to Pending?  I found this page but it doesn't seem to work:
[problem in magento default order status changes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8787/problem-in-magento-default-order-status-changes)